# Trouble with javascript API imports and exports

Tags: javascript, api, export, dropbox-api

I'm having trouble importing the Dropbox dependency for a scrimba course titled "Build an expense organizer with ES6 and Dropbox". I'd like to practice with the Dropbox API on my own computer, but I'm having trouble connecting the dropbox SDK with my project. I've installed the dependency, but I'm stuck at this error in my terminal console:

`SyntaxError: The requested module 'dropbox' does not provide an export named 'Dropbox'`

And then, I tried the older ‘require’ method, and got this:

```
var Dropbox = require('dropbox').Dropbox;
              ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I've tried it without using the require keyword as well:

```
import { Dropbox } from 'dropbox';
         ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'dropbox' does not provide an export named 'Dropbox'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:92:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:107:20)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:167:24)
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "z-dropbox-file-organizer-scrimba",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "scrimba course",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "dropbox": "^4.0.30",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Is there something I’m not accounting for? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem! I removed  `"type": "module"` from my package.json file that I added myself earlier on (because of something I googled, i forgot why). But I guess I don't quite understand what ESM is. I understand 'require' was the old way, and 'import' is the new ES6 way. But removing this allowed my script to run in my terminal!